# Single-word verb which means "to make more obvious"

Tags: single-word-requests

What single-word verb should I use to mean "to make more obvious"?

Here's the sentence in which I want to use such word:

"Our company wants to ___________ our online presence.

Comment: Highlight, focus on.

Comment: Advertise, announce, expose, showcase, promote …

Answer (score 2):

The word that's often used with "online presence" (and similar expressions) is [**expand**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/expand):

- [What steps can you take to expand your online presence?](https://www.wesayhowhigh.com/blog/article/what-steps-can-you-take-to-expand-your-online-presence)
- [7 Digital Tips to Expand Your Brand Presence and Reach](https://digitalmarketinginstitute.com/en-us/blog/19-07-16-7-digital-tips-to-expand-your-brand-presence)
- [4 Easy Ways To Expand Your Online Presence](https://www.theselfemployed.com/marketing/4-easy-ways-to-expand-your-online-presence/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several words you might use. The following come to mind:

"Our company wants to **magnify** our online presence.

"Our company wants to **spread out** our online presence.

> [**magnify**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/magnify)
>   To increase the apparent size of (an object), especially by means of a lens, instrument, or device.
>   [**spread out**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/spread+out)
>   extend in one or more directions

Examples from the web:

- [We **magnify** your online visibility by increasing your conversions ...](https://graphixide.com/)
- [**Magnify** your online presence with our strategic SEO & digital marketing.](https://www.advanceecomsolutions.com/)
- [It's a great way to instantly get your name in front of potential clients while we continue to **magnify** your online presence with long-term strategies like SEO.](http://www.jurisnimbus.com/legal-marketing-services/online-advertising/)

Answer (score 0):

"Our company wants to **[highlight](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/highlight)** our online presence.  TFD

> To make prominent; emphasize

Answer (score 0):

"Our company wants to [**increase**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/increase) our online presence."

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1** : to make greater : AUGMENT
>
> // She *increased* her wealth substantially.